# Опечатки в справке в разделе Сlosed Questions

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В заголовке: `замарожен` -> `заморожен`.

В самой статье: `приостановить` -> `заморозить` в последних двух абзацах.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: в заголовке появился лишний пробел -  “ заморожен”